# v-text-field textarea default height change?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using v-text-filed and in that, I am using textarea. I want to change the default height of  textarea and make it small. Is it possible to do this?

```
            <v-text-field
              name="input-1"
              label="Label Text"
              textarea
            ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: add e.g. `rows="2"` ?

Comment: @Traxo It is working now, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add `rows` property

```
<v-text-field
    name="input-1"
    label="Label Text"
    textarea
    rows="2"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: How this works? I do not see such parameters for the v-text-field comment as `textarea` or `rows`.

Comment: @Vitomir Which Vuetify version are you using? In Vuetify 3 there is textarea component, so you might want to see relevant docs for that. My Answer was for older vuetify versions, so it could be outdated.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Vuetify 2. There is also a textarea component, but I do not want to work like that.
And here, we do not have this - https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props

Are you using even older version of Vuetify ?

Comment: @Vitomir, Apologies for inconvenience. It's possible that I have answered the question before Vuetify 2 was released. Please see other answers or docs for up-to-date solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use textarea, I think use `<v-textarea>` tag is better. The example code is:

```html
  <v-textarea
    name="content"
    hint="hint text"
    rows="2"
  ></v-textarea>
```

you also follow this [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textareas/#usage) to get more details