# Vuetify - How to change the v-textarea row-height?

Tags: vue.js, textarea, vuetify.js

I would like to change the font size. But if I do this then the row height does not change. I tried using row-height = "40" to do this. Unfortunately this does not work. I've tested with the vue development extension which props v-textarea has. There I see a rowHeight. But this has no effect, too.

```
    <v-textarea
        value="The Woodman set to work at once,and so sharp was his axe that the tree was soon chopped nearly through."
        row-height="40"
        class="headline"
     ></v-textarea>
```

---

[Vuetify Guide -> Textarea](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textarea)

Prop-Name =**row-height** (Height value for each row)

Default= 24

Type = number | string

---

Thanks a lot, Chris

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706964/v-text-field-textarea-default-height-change

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `rows="4"` property to change the height of the `text-area`. To change the `row-height` you can add a css class

```
.v-textarea textarea {
      line-height: 40px;
 }
```

[See my example](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/wOgJxN)

Comment: If the above solution did not work, you can also try `.v-text-field--box>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot, .v-text-field--full-width>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot, .v-text-field--outline>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot{
        min-height: 40px !important;
    }`   and remove the margin like:     `.v-text-field--box input,.v-text-field--full-width input,.v-text-field--outline input {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }` and make sure you do it globally (i.e in App.vue)

Comment: This works so long as not using a scoped style. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same problem with you, and the css solution didn't suffice as the line-height value would not be reactive.

Thankfully, in the latest component documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textarea), its is now clear that the **auto-grow** prop is required in order for the **row-height** prop to be applied:

> **row-height**:
> type number | string, default 24
>
> description:
> Height value for each row. **Requires the use of the auto-grow prop.**

Answer (score 0):

Some times it don't work if you were set [style scope]. That what is working for me. I used here an attribues + important operator and it works even with style scope option.

```
    <v-textarea text-narrow>
    ...
    </v-textarea>

    <style scope>
    [text-narrow] {
        line-height: 1.1 !important;
    }
    </style>
```